# Fix an issue with a jQuery portfolio filter

Tags: jquery, filter, portfolio

I've been working on my online portfolio trying to create a filterable section. Basically, I'm trying to get the following result:

clicking on a tag in the filter section should display the appropriate works, hiding the rest

I'm not sure how I can achieve this, and I don't want to use a jQueru plugin. The last two lines of my code work fine, but there's something wrong elsewhere.

```
$('.filters li').click(function() {

    if ($(this).attr('id') == '#all') {
    $('#works ul li').animate({
        opacity : '0'
    });
    }
    else {
        $(this).trigger('show');
        $(this).trigger('hide');
    }


    $('.filters li').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

Here's the HTML code:

```
<ul class="filters">
<li id="all">Tous</li>
<li id="webdesign">Web Design</li>
```

```
<section id="works">
<ul>
    <li class="webdesign">
    <span class="details">
        <h4>title</h4>
        <p>skills</p>
    </span>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/365/240" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="wordpress">
    <span class="details">
        <h4>title</h4>
        <p>skills</p>
    </span>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/365/240" alt="">
    </li>
</ul>
</section>
```

Comment: .trigger('show')? what does that means? you cannot trigger methods like this. You just can trigger events like 'click'.

Comment: Yes, that's true, I try a lot of things, and I forgot to delete this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by declaring our variables, and caching our selectors to both elements:

```
var filtr = $("#filters"), 
    works = $("#works li"), 
    curnt = "current",
    clsID = "";
```

Next we setup *event delegation*, meaning we only bind one event, yet we leverage the behavior of bubbling to listen for events that were initiated by clicking on a nested `li` element:

```
filtr.on("click", "li", applyFilter);
```

Lastly, we declare the behavior of our handler. In this case, we capture the `id` of the list item clicked (or "all" if no id exists), and we use that to filter the list items within our `#works` element:

```
function applyFilter () {
    clsID = this.id || "all";
    clsID === "all"
        ? works.removeClass(curnt).show()
        : works.not("." + clsID).removeClass(curnt).hide()
               .siblings().addClass(curnt).show();
}​​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mrU4Y/10/

Comment: It works perfectly on jsfiddle but, when I add one more <li> on the #works section with a webdesign class, the filter hide all the items.